# Oxyplot: how to set up a simple column chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I have to implement a simple Column Chart output in a WPF project. I have chosen the OxyPlot Library for it. Design Pattern is of course MVVM.
The relevant source code parts can be seen below. What I get, when I run the project is an empty chart with categories 1 thru 5 on the x axis (which is correct) and values 0 thru 100 on the y axis (which is correct also, as i am supposed to display percentages).

The data collections (named "difficulties" for the category axis and "percentages" for the values axis" are correctly filled with values, I´ve checked that one.

But there are no columns displayed. So I wonder what I am doing wrong. I have built my example according to [this oxyplot demo](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WpfExample1&referringTitle=Home) and based on an example we got presented at the wpf class at university.

Any suggestions?

Regards
Roland

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace GeoCaching.Wpf.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PropertyChangedEventArgs called " + propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Statistics Model itself goes here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GeoCaching.BL;
using GeoCaching.BL.Interfaces;
using GeoCaching.BL.Factories;
using GeoCaching.DAL.Common.Domain;
using GeoCaching.Wpf.ViewModels;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Wpf;
using OxyPlot.Annotations;
using OxyPlot.Axes;

namespace GeoCaching.Wpf.ViewModels
{
    public class StatisticsVM : ViewModelBase
    {

        private IStatisticsMgr statManager;
        Dictionary<int, double> testList;
        List<int> difficulties;
        List<double> percentages;

        public StatisticsVM()
        {
            PlotModel = new PlotModel();
            this.difficulties = new List<int>();
            this.percentages = new List<double>();
            LoadData();
            SetUpModel();
        }

        private PlotModel plotModel;
        public PlotModel PlotModel
        {
            get { return plotModel; }
            set { plotModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("PlotModel"); }
        }


        private void SetUpModel()
        {
            var temp = new PlotModel("difficulties distribution");
            OxyPlot.Axes.CategoryAxis catAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.CategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
            OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis valAxis   = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, 0, 100);

            valAxis.MinimumPadding = 0;
            valAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = 0;

            OxyPlot.Series.ColumnSeries cs = new OxyPlot.Series.ColumnSeries();
            cs.ItemsSource = percentages;

            temp.Axes.Add(catAxis);
            temp.Axes.Add(valAxis);
            temp.Series.Add(cs);

            PlotModel = temp;
            PlotModel.RefreshPlot(true);

        }


        //fetch statistics data from
        //database
        private void LoadData()
        {
            statManager = StatisticsMgrFactory.GetStatisticsManager();
            testList = new Dictionary<int, double>();

            testList = statManager.GroupByDifficulty();

            //extract keys and values
            //for statistical display on axes
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,double> item in testList)
            {
                difficulties.Add(item.Key);
                percentages.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code behind the xaml window:

```
using GeoCaching.Wpf.ViewModels;

namespace GeoCaching.Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ChartTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ChartTest : Window
    {
        public ChartTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new StatisticsVM();
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml itself:

```
<Window x:Class="GeoCaching.Wpf.ChartTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.codeplex.com"
        Title="ChartTest" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>


        <oxy:Plot Title="Bar series" LegendPlacement="Outside" LegendPosition="RightTop" LegendOrientation="Vertical" Model="{Binding PlotModel}">

        </oxy:Plot>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe your issue is coming from within the `SetupModel` method, specifically, this line:

```
cs.ItemsSource = percentages;
```

I've been working with oxyPlot column charts and I've never been able to get a chart to work if I set the `ItemSource` property. Instead, I have to add a `new ColumnItem()` for every item within my item source.

Example:

```
foreach (double pc in percentages)
{
    catAxis.ActualLabels.Add (/*Add your difficulty labels here for each column*/);
    cs.Items.Add (new ColumnItem () { Value = pc });
}
```

I know this question is quite old, but I thought id share this for anyone else who's having trouble. (Feel free to update my answer if you know why using the actual `ItemSource` property doesn't work!)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.  Could this be a bug in OxyPlot?